# Eliminar ID con un boton

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

en estos momentos estoy trabajando en una página web como proyecto final.
Antes de continuar con mi explicación, quiero resaltar que no se casi nada de HTML, CSS y PHP, esto que llevo es el resultado de distintas búsquedas y copypaste de códigos terceros.

Estoy revuelto en un problema ya que no puedo eliminar un registro hecho.

Este sería el html que tengo (muestro solo el que según yo se utiliza para mandar el id):

```
 <?php
session_start();

require("../PHP/db.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['correo'])){

} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cuenta</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/paginas.css">
 </head>
<body>
<header>
  <div class = "logoheader">
    <img src="../IMG/IconoBlanco.png" class="avatar" alt="Avatar 
Image">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li center> <a href="taxis.php">Taxis</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="choferes.php">Choferes</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="rutas.php">Rutas</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="cuenta.php">Cuenta</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  
  
  <div class="Cajabts">
   Nombres: <br> 
   Apellidos: <br>
  <form method = "POST" action="../PHP/subirfoto.php">
  
  <div class="boton">
    <input type="submit" name = "cambiar-foto" value="Agregar o modificar foto.">
    <input type="button" name="modificarcuenta" value = "Modificar cuenta">
    <a href = "../PHP/logout.php"><input type="button" name="cerrarsesion" value = "Cerrar sesion"></a>
    </div>
    </form>
  
  
    
    
    <!--BORRADO DE REGISTROS-->
    <form method = "POST" action="../PHP/borrado.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value = "<?=$row["ID"];?>">
    <input type="submit" name="eliminarcuenta" value = "Eliminar cuenta">
    </form>

    </div>    
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>Moving</p>
    </footer>
```

Y este es el PHP en donde estoy recibiendo el id para su eliminación:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("db.php");

$id = $_POST["id"];

$eliminado = "DELETE FROM usuarios2 WHERE ID = '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $eliminado);

if($resultado){

session_destroy();
header("Location: ../PAGINAS/index.php");

}else{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Este es el PHP de mi BD:

```
<?php

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","validar")or die(
"error de conexion");
?>
```

Comment: En la linea de $id = $_POST['id'], cambialo por $_GET['id'] y verifica que venga ese valor

Answer (score 2):

En el HTML estás mezclando las dos opciones que tienes:

a) Por enlace, únicamente GET:

```
<a href = "../PHP/borrado.php?id=<?=$row["ID"];?>">
  <button>Eliminar cuenta</button>
</a>
```

b) Por formulario, POST o GET (has elegido POST con el atributo `method`):

```
<form method = "POST" action="../PHP/borrado.php">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value = "<?=$row["ID"];?>">
<button>Eliminar cuenta</button>
</form>
```

En el PHP debes recibir el valor con:

a) `$id = $_GET['id'];`

b) `$id = $_POST['id'];`

El resto tiene aspecto de estar bien. Si algo falla, amplía la pregunta con el error o fallo que obtienes y ampliaré la respuesta para solucionarlo. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola, probe la solución que me proporcionaste, pero sigue sin poder borrar los registros :c

Comment: Edita la pregunta con el código que has modificado, algo estas haciendo mal, como te mencionaron estas mezclando el metodo **get y post**.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia listo bro, ya edite la pregunta y puse el codigo modificado. Pero sigo sin poder hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Aporta también la estructura de base de datos y, sobre todo, el mensaje de error que obtienes para poder depurarlo

Comment: @DavidJP ya aporte el codigo de la BD. Es que no me sale ningun error en pantalla, simplemente no elimina los registros

Comment: Es que tu código no nos dice mucho, pueden ser varios factores, realmente te imprime el **echo $row["id"];** en el input oculto?, otra cosa, en tu PHP donde recibes dicho id verifica que realmente este llegando algo con **if(isset())**, si quieres un ejemplo me dices.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia en realidad si me gustaria un ejemplo, y no, al parecer no estoy recibiendo nada en el PHP ya que si elimino yo el id manualmente si se elimina, entonces el id no se esta enviando

Comment: @DerekRiosRamirez para poder ayudarte mejor agrega el archivo HTML completo, tu PHP que te da el **$row["id"];** y el PHP  que elimina, todos completos, de mientras te dejo un ejemplo con **isset**.

Answer (score 0):

Observando que escogiste el método **POST**, comprobamos que el dato este llegando con **Isset** de esta manera y vemos donde esta el fallo.

```js
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");

//SI RECIBE DATO
if(isset($_POST["id"]){
$id = $_POST["id"];

echo $id;
//COMENTAMOS DE MOMENTO ESTO, PARA VERIFICAR SOLO SI LLEGA EL DATO
/*$eliminado = "DELETE FROM usuarios2 WHERE ID = '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $eliminado);

  if($resultado){
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: ../PAGINAS/index.php");

  }else{
  echo "error";
  }*/
//SI NO LLEGA NADA
}else{
  echo "NO RECIBI NINGUN DATO";
}
?>
```

Prueba y dime donde cae, si te imprime el **echo con el id** el siguiente paso es descomentar la consulta, voy a ir editando la respuesta según vallas haciendo pruebas.

Comment: no esta recibiendo el ID, me manda directamente al else

Comment: ya proporcione el html completo tambien

Comment: es que lo que quiero es poder obtener el id del inicio de sesion, osea, que si yo inicie sesion, poder obtener el id de este registro y poder eliminarlo.